# How to try solving this bizarre inequality?

Tags: inequality, summation

I am trying to prove that $$\sum_{n\geqslant 1}\frac{1}{\lfloor e^n\rceil}<5/9$$

Part of this process is to prove that this inequality works without using tedious numerical approximation (stop the sum at a large number), but rather an elegant one.

I tried to separate

$$\lfloor e^n\rceil=f(e^n-1/2)+f(e^n-3/2)+\cdots$$

where

$$f(x)=\frac{1+\text{sign }x}{2}$$

but that got nowhere fast.

sign(x)= https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sign(x)

Comment: What is $\lfloor x\rceil$?

Comment: round(x) @ChristianBlatter For example, $\lfloor 3.2\rceil=3$ and $\lfloor 3.7\rceil=4$

Comment: Where is this problem from? Also are you sure this is right, and the inequality isn't the other way around? For $n=10^9$, the sum is $0.555053$ whereas $5/9=0.5555\cdots$. At this point you can probably just bound the tail error by $\sum_{k>n}1/e^{k-1}$:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B1%2FRound%5BExp%5Bn%5D%5D,%7Bn,10%5E9%7D%5D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$f(n):=\sum_{k=1}^n{1\over\lfloor e^k\rceil}\ .$$
Numerical evidence shows that, e.g., $f(15)\approx0.555053$, and that $f$ does not grow "essentially" after that. I therefore conjecture that you claim is false. For a proof use the estimate
$${1\over\lfloor e^n\rceil}-{1\over e^n}={e^n-\lfloor e^n\rceil\over e^n\>\lfloor e^n\rceil}\leq{1/2\over e^n(e^n-1/2)}\leq e^{-2n}\qquad(n\geq1)\ ,$$
and show that the terms with $k\geq 15$ (or $\geq n_0$ for a slightly larger $n_0$) will never bring the sum to $>0.555555\ldots$

Comment: I accidentally wrote the question backwards. However, your proof is great anyways.